# dialog box with error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sdIntContent' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, simpledialog

i have a dialog box that i use in all my internal pages it works fine from home page but when page 1 kicks in i get an error that says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sdIntContent' of undefined and the dialog box does not appear anymore

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){ 
    $(document).on ('click','#firstbutton', function () {        
        $('#footerdialog').simpledialog2({themeDialog: 'c'});
    });
    $(document).on('click','#first',function () {
        window.location.href = "#first";
        $('#footerdialog').simpledialog2('close');
    }); 
    $(document).on('click','#second',function () {
        window.location.href = "#second";
        $('#footerdialog').simpledialog2('close');
    }); 
});//]]>  

</script>
<!--script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){ 
    $(document).on ('click','#secondbutton', function () {        
        $.mobile.changePage('#secondpage', {
            transition: 'slideup',
            changeHash: true,
            role: 'dialog'
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click','#third',function () {
        window.location.href = "#third";
    }); 
    $(document).on('click','#fourth',function () {
        window.location.href = "#fourth";
    }); 
});//]]>  

</script-->
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed"  class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup"  data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="navbar"  data-theme="c">
            <ul>
                <li>    
                    <button id="firstbutton" data-rel="dialog" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">first button</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button id="secondbutton" data-rel="dialog" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">second button</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <div data-role="dialog" id="firstpage" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" class="ui-dialog my-dialog ui-dialog-contain">
            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#" id="first" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: white; background:red;">first</a>
                <a href="#" id="second" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: white; background:red;">second</a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="dialog" id="secondpage" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#" id="third" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:green;">third</a>
                <a href="#" id="fourth" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:green;">fourth</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="footerdialog" style="display:none" data-options='{"mode":"blank","headerText":"Dialog","headerClose":false,"blankContent":true}'> 
    <div  style="padding: 15px;">       
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button id="first" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">first button</button>    
            </li>
            <li>    
                <button id="second" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">second button</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button id="third" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">third button</button>
            </li>
        </ul>           
    </div>
    </div>          

<div data-role="page" id="first" data-theme="c" data-transition="slideup">
    <div data-role="header" ></div> 
    <div data-role="content" style="text-align: center;" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="first page">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="right">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="first" href="#">first</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="left">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="esecond" href="#">second</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-c">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:green;">first</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: Black; background:yellow;">second</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: white; background:black;">third</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:red;">fourth</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<div data-role="content" id="home">
    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed"  class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup"  data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="navbar"  data-theme="c">
            <ul>
                <li>    
<button id="firstbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">first button</button>
                </li>
                <li>
<button id="secondbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">second button</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="c" data-transition="slideup">
    <div data-role="header" ></div> 
    <div data-role="content" style="text-align: center;" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="Second Page">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="right">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="first" href="#">first</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="left">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="esecond" href="#">second</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-c">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:green;">first</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: Black; background:yellow;">second</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: white; background:black;">third</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:red;">fourth</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<div data-role="content" id="home">
    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed"  class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup"  data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="navbar"  data-theme="c">
            <ul>
                <li>    
<button id="firstbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">first button</button>
                </li>
                <li>
<button id="secondbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">second button</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="third" data-theme="c" data-transition="slideup">
    <div data-role="content"  style="text-align: center;" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="third page">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="right">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="first" href="#">first</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="left">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="esecond" href="#">second</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-c">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:green;">first</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: Black; background:yellow;">second</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: white; background:black;">third</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:red;">fourth</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div data-role="content" id="home">
    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed"  class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup"  data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="navbar"  data-theme="c">
            <ul>
                <li>    
<button id="firstbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">first button</button>
                </li>
                <li>
<button id="secondbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">second button</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="fourth" data-theme="c" data-transition="slideup">
    <div data-role="content"  style="text-align: center;" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="fourth page">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="right">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="first" href="#">first</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">
              <div data-role="fieldcontain"  align="left">
                <a style="width:25%" data-role="button" id="esecond" href="#">second</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-c">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:green;">first</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: Black; background:yellow;">second</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: white; background:black;">third</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="false" style="color: White; background:red;">fourth</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div data-role="content" id="home">
    <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed"  class="ui-footer ui-bar-a ui-footer-fixed slideup"  data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="navbar"  data-theme="c">
            <ul>
                <li>    
<button id="firstbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">first button</button>
                </li>
                <li>
<button id="secondbutton" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">second button</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's a 3rd party library issue (simpledialog2).

Comment: yes ive looked into it but i dont know how to fix it or what to do to make it work.any ideas?

Comment: why dont you use jQM dialogs?

Comment: i tried but wasnt able to run so i did the other way but if it cant be done then maybe i will have to make jQM dialog run.no other way around the Cannot read property 'sdIntContent' error?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using dialogs? I can assist you. I couldn't reproduce this problem based on your given details.

Comment: i want to use a nav bar at bottom page of all my internal pages as a navigation.like in the first botton 1stbutton and the other 2ndbutton. if i click 1stbutton a dialog box will appear with a list of button "page 1" "page 2" "page 3" and when 2ndbutton is clicked a dialog box will appear with a list of button "page 4" "page 5" "page 6" and when im in "page 1" same nav bar with same function will appear so with page 2 page 3 page 4 and so on.

Comment: In your navbar, you're using `button` tag not anchor `a`. Use anchors, its working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HAU33/

Comment: yeah it works but still have 1 problem when im in page 1 the footer nav bar doesn't work when i click it dialog does not appear

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40165/discussion-between-omar-and-satine-kianne)

Comment: @Omar please check chat again thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following mistakes in you code.

1. You are using `button` instead of `a` tags in your navbar. The correct syntax is as follows:

   ```
   <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="c">
     <ul>
       <li>
         <a href="#firstpage" data-rel="dialog" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">first button</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#secondpage" data-rel="dialog" data-corners="false" data-theme="c">second button</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   ```
2. You have given the same `id` to several elements, `id`s' should be **unique**.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HAU33/)**